# Laravel controller passing value as Vue prop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have a *Laravel* route leading to the *index* function of my controller with a passed ID, where I return the id in a view

```
public function index($id)
{
    return view('progress')
        ->with('identifier', $id);
}
```

In the component loaded in said view I'm trying to access the `identifier` as a prop in my vue script

```
props: ['identifier'],
    methods: {
        getInformation() {
            this.$root.$emit('fetchEvent');
        },
    },
    mounted () {
        console.dir(this.identifier);
    }
```

However, my console says undefined and I can't figure out how to get the passed `identifier` as a prop.

What am I doing wrong?

update:

full template code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="tab-content">                
                <item-component 
                    :web-identifier="identifier"
                ></item-component>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>


<script>
export default {
   props: ['identifier'],
    methods: {
        getInformation() {
            this.$root.$emit('fetchEvent');
        },
    },
    mounted () {
        console.dir(this.identifier);
    }
}
</script>
```

blade:

```
<div>
<task-detail-component></task-detail-component>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you pass the prop in your progress template

Comment: The bottom section of code is my progress template. I guess that's what I'm not sure of, I'm trying to make identifier accessible within the template through props

Comment: please share the progress template code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim there isn't much else but I shared it

Comment: where and how you're calling that component in blade template

Comment: I just added that as well @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in blade template pass that data as follows :

```
<div>
<task-detail-component :identifier="{{$identifier}}"></task-detail-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so is there a reason why my console portion shows undefined?

Comment: or try `<task-detail-component :identifier="{{$identifier}}"></task-detail-component>` with `$identifier`

Comment: on building I get a compile error for unexpected token {

Comment: It is. Blade view injected variables are not available to the browser unless you explicitly bind them that way.

Comment: I see now, that got it I believe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your template where you need to pass your `identifier` it will be like this

```
<div>
<task-detail-component :identifier="{{$identifier}}"></task-detail-component>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I see, so why is the console printing undefined where I'm trying to show it in the console?

Comment: did you make sure that you pass the `identifier` variable to view that contains this component?

Comment: You can see where I;m passing it to the view in my controller above

Comment: try to make it as api and fetch it in your component from ajax with axios